# 'sudo tee' command gone wrong | Removing a source.list that can't be read?

Tags: package-management, software-center, software-sources, tee

This has happened twice where I followed instructions on installing software and then having the software center open then close immediately as a result of running the commands from the instructions. The first incident happened when I was trying to install Mono. I followed their instructions up to `sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`. The terminal stopped was not responding so I put the command back in and it just echoed it. So I closed it and tried it again with no luck. So then I wanted to check if the software center had just the Mono cs compiler and that's when the software center started closing immediately after opening and ubuntu gave me this error

```
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 2 in the source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I formatted my computer back to an earlier backup being unable to find an answer to this error and not knowing what I did wrong.

Now I tried installing Spotify and they have a similar list of instructions.

> 2. Add the Spotify repository
>
>    ```
>    echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
>    ```

So I did until this point where the terminal was not responding again. I tried 'exit' to close it, but it just echoed the command. After I manually closed it, I checked the software center to see if I had done the same thing again, and I did. Software center will not stay open and returned this same error when I try `apt-get autoremove`

```
E: Type 'exit' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

My first question is how do I remove/repair the list, and my second is how do I use `sudo tee...` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first command

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

is wrong. The command waits for an input and writes into

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

Therefore simply remove the file

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

and start the correct command again and don't forget the

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

Your second command

```
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

is correct. After this command you have the line

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`. Check with

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

---

The command `tee` read from standard input and write to standard output and files. Two examples

```
echo "foo" | tee bar
```

writes the string `foo` into the file `bar`. The previous content will be overwritten.

```
echo "foo" | tee -a bar
```

appends the string `foo` to the given file.

The command `tee bar` reads from the standard input and writes into the file `bar`

Start a test with

```
tee bar
```

Type some words and stop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. Now start

```
cat bar
```

to see your changes.

*Example*

```
% tee bar
foo
foo
bar
bar
^C
% cat bar
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I went to 'other software' in software and updates and removed the misbehaving repository from the list. Then I did `sudo apt-get autoremove` which it didn't stop at the error this time so I was able to process to `sudo apt-get update` and I was able to open the software center again and keep it open. I still get the class system error saying 'exit' is not know on line 2 in spotify.list. I still don't know how to remove that.